# Postgresql - UPDATE with different WHERE clasules

Tags: postgresql, update

I've written a long Query for updating a table, with some large `WITH` selects. I want to update some columns during some condition and other if other conditions. I tried to write an easy example

```
WITH sub_select(SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM my_large_table)
UPDATE my_second_table
SET first_col = column1
WHERE column3 > 1
SET second_col = column2
WHERE column3 = 1
FROM sub_selection;
```

What I can do is write it as two separate queries, but I prefer to solve it with one query, any suggestions?

```
with sub_select(SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM my large_table)
UPDATE my_second_table
SET first_col = column1
WHERE column3 > 1
FROM sub_selection;
with sub_select(SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM my large_table)
UPDATE my_second_table
SET second_col = column2
WHERE column3 = 1
FROM sub_selection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you gave tables and columns, but something like this might work. Basically, move the WHERE into a case statement and set the column equal to itself if the condition is not met.

```
WITH sub_select(SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM my_large_table)
UPDATE my_second_table
SET first_col = case when column3 > 1 then column1 else first_col end
, second_col = case when column 3 = 1 then column2 else second_col end
FROM sub_selection;
```

Comment: Nice! Just what I was aiming for! I would have given the proper tables but that would just complicate the question.